# addEventListener code is not working after i added click too

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
var numofDrumButton = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0 ; i<numofDrumButton; i++){

  document.querySelector(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

     var audio = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
     audio.play();

  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this:

```
var drumButton = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");
for (var i = 0; i < drumButton.length; i++){
   drumButton[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var audio = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      audio.play();
   });
}
```

You have to use the same variable in the for loop :)

Comment: thank you Shannon. But what did i do worng?

Comment: You used a different variable inside of the for loop than the one in for `(var i = 0 ; i<numofDrumButton; i++)`, so the program will try and select [i] of an element that wasn't initially stated.
Notice how instead of setting the first variable to `document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length`, I set one variable `var drumButton = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");`, got the length of it in the for loop `drumButton.length`, and finally looped through each one with `drumButton[i]`

Comment: Refer to [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) > Statement 1. Ask any questions if you are unsure. Also, please accept my answer if I helped you.